# Multi-Domain Shared Hosting

Tags: domain, root

I have a shared hosting pack with 2 domains, one is the default domain bought with the pack, and the second will be pointed to a sub-directory within my root.

The problem is that I want both the domains to point to sub-directories.

The current architecture is:

1- domain1.com -> www/

2- domain2.com -> www/domain2/

and because this is not very tidy, as the second domain's directory will look like a sub-directory in the first domain, I want the architecture to be like this:

1- domain1.com -> www/domain1/

2- domain2.com -> www/domain2/

to keep a clean tree.

I think this would be achieved by a .htaccess file located in the root www/

So, how to do it? and is there any side effects?

thanks.

Comment: Which shared hosting?

Comment: at OVH http://www.ovh.com/

Comment: Then you need to discuss this with OVH support.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need to access the Apache config and change the directory there for your Vhosts.

Comment: how to do that in a shared hosting (OVH)

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen done in some cases is people get an admin domain name and then place the individual sites in separate directories.

```
admindomain.com -> www/
   domain1.com -> www/domain1
   domain2.com -> www/domain2
```